# NSOutlineView viewForTableColumn: non-inherited method not documented

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsoutlineview

I've seen [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8382577/412107) to `outlineView:viewForTableColumn:item:` in an `NSOutlineView`'s delegate.   And I've got a Mac app where it's being used and called by Apple code (I can put a breakpoint in the method and see it in the stack).  But I can't find documentation on it anywhere.  It's not in Apple's documentation on [NSOutlineViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOutlineViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) or [NSOutlineViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSOutlineViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).  It is, however, in NSOutlineView.h in my project (in the headers for the AppKit framework), and a comment above it refers `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` in `NSTableViewDelegate`.

Why would this method (not inherited from `NSTableView` since it's a different signature than `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:`) not be documented?  Can anyone clarify or post details?

Answer (score 0):

`NSOutlineView` is a subclass of `NSTableView`. All of the documentation for `NSTableView` applies to `NSOutlineView` as well.

You need to read the documentation for all of the super classes to get an understanding of what methods you can send to `NSOutlineView`. You also need to read the documentation for all categories and protocols that are applied to `NSOutlineView` and all of it's super classes.

If all of it were documented in one page, it would be several hundred megabytes of text. There are literally tens of thousands of valid messages you can send to an `NSOutlineView`, mostly added as categories on `NSObject`.

For example, the `frame` method is documented in the `NSView` page. And the `initWithCoder:` method is documented in the `NSCoding protocol` page. You need to know about these methods, because `frame` is the only way to change the size of the outline view and `initWithCoder:` is the constructor that will be used if your outline view is created from an xib file - so that's what you have to override if you create a subclass.

Use command click and/or option-click on the method name to find where it is in the documentation. Also beware that some things that work on an `NSTableView` do not work on an `NSOutlineView`. I'm not sure if viewForTableColumn is one of those.

Comment: There is `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` in `NSTableViewDelegate` [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), but it's a different signature and the last argument is `NSInteger` instead of `id` like the one in `NSOutlineView`.  I am aware that superclass methods are not in subclass documentation, but this does not appear to be an inherited method.

Comment: In my copy of NSOutlineView.h it says this: "View Based OutlineView: See the delegate method -tableView:viewForTableColumn:row: in NSTableView." so they are basically the same method, just with different parameters because of how NSOutlineView works different to NSTableView

Comment: In a table view, everything is based on a row index. In an outline view the data source returns an objectForRowIndex: and everything else uses that object instead of a row index.

Comment: Mine says the same, but I'd still expect there to be documentation of where the object comes from (in place of the row ID).

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `NSOutlineView`? You are responsible for creating the object yourself and providing it to `NSOutlineView`. It will give your object back to you in many different places, including this one. File a bug report to their documentation team if you want, but I think it's pretty clear.